# latexdiff: exclude caption text

Tags: latexdiff

Is anyone aware on an option in latexdiff that lets one exclude the caption from appearing in the diff?

E.g. whenever I move a figure around, latexdiff will keep the caption text at the old place, mark it as deleted and in the new place of the figure the caption text is marked as added text.
 I tried to disable diffs for figures, tables etc with the config file

```
PICTUREENV=(?:picture|DIFnomarkup|tabular|tabularx)[\w\d*@]*
PICTUREENV=(?:picture|DIFnomarkup|tikzpicture|float)[\w\d*@]*
FLOATENV=(?:figure|table|plate)[\w\d*@]*
```

but to be honest I wasn't so sure what I was doing and found the manual difficult to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the following right after your \begin{document}  and using '-f FLOATSAFE' option (which is the default) all marking of changes in floats should be suppressed:

```
\newcommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{}
\newcommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{}
```

A more elegant way to do this would be to use the -p option to define a custom preamble with these commands.

You can also achieve a similar outcome with the PICTUREENV option as you tried, but instead of 'float' in the second line you should add 'figure' and 'table'. Note that in your config file example the definition of PICTUREENV in your second line will overwrite the definition in the first line - you need to add further environments in the same line, separated by '|'